# Python : Specify an instrument in an existing MIDI file or during the conversion to WAVE file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

Is it possible to specify an instrument in an existing MIDI file or during the conversion of this MIDI to WAVE?

I'm using Python in Windows 10.

Comment: This depends on what software you are using for the conversion.

Comment: For the conversion I just use MuseScore CLI.

Comment: Why does it depend on the software used for the conversion midi to wave? Indeed I should be able to specify the instrument when generating the midi too. No? @CL.

Comment: Or even in the existing midi file, no?

Answer (score 0):

MIDI files contain program numbers. You can change them to get an entirely different instrument.

MuseScore uses SoundFont files for synthesizing the actual sounds. You can use a different SoundFont file to change the sounds of the instruments.